# Bootstrap tags input with type ahead freeInput

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead, bootstrap-tags-input

I want to use the bootstrap tags input jquery plugin with typeahead values.  It works great in that I see the typeahead values as I'm typing but I want to make it so the user can't input their own values.  Following the documentation from http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/bootstrap3/.  I tried the  freeInput: false variable but it's still allowing for any entry.  Here's the code:

```
$('#topics').tagsinput({
      typeahead: {
          source: ['one', 'two', 'three'],
          freeInput: false
        }
    });
```

See anything I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This code does not work, because you have a few errors in your code:
1)
https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#datasets
**source** should be function
2) change 'typehead' to 'typeheadjs' and free input send as param to tags input

```
    var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
    return function findMatches(q, cb) {
    var matches, substrRegex;

    // an array that will be populated with substring matches
    matches = [];

    // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
    substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

    // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
    // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
    $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
    if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
    // the typeahead jQuery plugin expects suggestions to a
    // JavaScript object, refer to typeahead docs for more info
    matches.push({ value: str });
    }
    });

    cb(matches);
    };
    };

    var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',
    'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
    'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana',
    'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
    'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
    'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
    'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
    'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
    'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
    ];        
    $('#the-basics .typeahead').tagsinput({
    typeaheadjs: {
        source: substringMatcher(str)
    },
    freeInput: false
    });
```